# im getting an error in insertion in database with c#

Tags: c#, sql

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace testofinsertion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conobj = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-442L7TS;Initial Catalog=insertionincsharp;User ID=sa;Password=bilal");
            try
            {
                conobj.Open();
                var query = "INSERT INTO user_registeration(user_name),(email),(course),(age),(phone_number) VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+textBox2.Text+textBox3.Text+textBox4.Text+textBox5.Text+"')";
                SqlCommand commanddd = new SqlCommand(query,conobj);
                commanddd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getting error "Incorrect syntax near ','."

Comment: That's a SQL injection bug. Any extra `'` in one of the values will result in an invalid query or worse, execute an unexpected query. Think what would happen if one of the values was `'); DROP TABLE Users; --`. Don't create SQL queries by concatenating input, use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: and the question is ?   Please share more input, for example the line on which this error occurs, and share what your tried to solve this.

Comment: The rest of the query is invalid too. Instead of specifying a list of columns, it puts them in parentheses. You should test your query in a tool like SSMS or Azure Data Studio to ensure it works *before* hard-coding it in your application.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your SQL is valid. You need to separate columns by a comma. I believe it should be:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO user_registeration (user_name, email, course, age, phone_number) VALUES (....)";
```